# Codeigniter inserts true as 0 in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I can't figure out why Codeigniter inserts 0 in mysql Db even thought that value is true. Let me show you an example

This is My_model where insert happens

```
function insert($data,$tablename=""){
        if($tablename=="")
            $tablename = $this->table;
        var_dump($data);
        $this->db->insert($tablename,$data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```

This is var dump data

```
<b>array</b> <i>(size=23)</i>
  'name' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'123123'</font> <i>(length=6)</i>
  'description' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'123123'</font> <i>(length=6)</i>
  'tourist_location' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'true'</font> <i>(length=4)</i>
  'approved_location' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'true'</font> <i>(length=4)</i>
</pre>
```

And this is the state in DB
[image]

This is my table structure
[image: table structure]

So where the hell is my code failing? Why if i insert 1 or 'true' the state in db table is 0?

If you need any additional information's, please let me know and i will provide.
Thank you for help!

Comment: Share code from where you are calling insert function ?

Comment: I think it rely doesn't matter since var is true just before i make insert statement, except if you see any other problems?

Comment: If you share that code , its hepful to you to fix your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the type wrong on your tourist_location and approved_location data.

You are actually telling the database to insert the string "true" into an integer field. The database will be expecting a single digit and when it receives your "true" it will try to convert it into an integer. The result is 0.

Can you manipulate the $data so it's more like

```
$data = array(
           'name' => 'xyz',
           'description' => 'somedescription',
           'tourist_location' => 1,
           'approved_location' => 1
        );
```

If you're using a form to submit this data then just have checkboxes like so

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tourist_location" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="approved_location" value="1">
```

If it's a select then something like this will work fine

```
<select name="tourist_location">
    <option value="0">No</option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
</select>
```

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: good job sir! thank you it was bugging me for hours and hours ;)

Comment: No worries. Databases generally happily accept whatever you chuck at them and they don't complain. It keeps you on your toes.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `BOOLEAN` as data type. So in that case it only allows you to use `0` either `1`.

```
If TRUE then its 1
If FALSE then its 0
```

---

**Your DB Structure**

[image]

---

[SQL General Data Types](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes_general.asp)

[image]